# How can I apply an operator to different elements of the same data frame without calling the elements via [row,column]?

Tags: r

First time asking a question. I tried searching in vain for an answer but can't seem to find exactly what I am looking for.

i have a small (2x2) data frame at the moment:

```
   status weighted.responses
1 control           3.872694
2 exposed           3.713198
```

What I want to be able to do is subtract 'Exposed' from 'Control' by calling out a specific name, as opposed to [2,2] - [1,2]. Reason being, there will be several more columns added to this data frame as time goes on.

I have tried to transpose the data frame, promote the rows to headers, and then remove the row being used for a header, but then I end up with a vector.

- Transposing also seems to turn my data frame to strings for some reason, which is another problem.

I have tried just taking the vector of 'weighted.responses', naming them accordingly, and subtracting, but then I run into a problem of having the new variable end up being a named number, which I don't want. At that point it just seemed like a waste of time and space for have several different lines for a problem I am sure.

I feel like I am running circles around a very simple solution, but I can't figure it out.

I am very appreciative of your time, and apologies for the formatting.

Comment: Perhaps you can post dummy data and expected output?

Comment: *"sorry, can't embed"*?  Why?  It's just a simple copy/paste.

Comment: I think they mean they can't embed the image. OP, for future use it's better to include your data as text within the question, e.g. the console output from `print(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways you can do this using `dplyr`/`tidyverse`. Note that functions like `spread` tend to work better for reshaping dataframes than `t()`, which turns your dataframe into a matrix and coerces all values to the same type. Examples of things you can do:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(
    status = c("Control", "Exposed"),
    response = c(3.87, 3.71)
)

df %>% spread(status, response) %>% summarize(diff = Control - Exposed)
# Output:
  diff
1 0.16

df %>%
    summarize(diff = response[status == "Control"] - response[status == "Exposed"])
# Output:
  diff
1 0.16
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I ended up going with the third option. I appreciate you taking your time to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

**1) subtraction** This will subtract row 1 from row 2 even if there are more than 2 columns.  It is assumed that the other columns are numeric and are to be differenced as well.  Note that -1 here means all columns except the first.

```
DF[2, -1] - DF[1, -1]
```

**2) rownames** Another way to do it is to convert the first column to row names and then do the subtraction:

```
DF1 <- DF[-1]
rownames(DF1) <- DF[[1]]
DF1["exposed", ] - DF1["control", ]
```

**3) lapply** This would also work:

```
data.frame(lapply(DF[-1], diff))
```